# Can we use Journey Data yet within SMS sends (that is sent via a journey)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect

I have a requirement to send an SMS with some appointment data in my Journey. I know in the past it was practically impossible to use the Journey Data, however a number of releases have past now and I'd like to know whether this is still the case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Journey Data for SMS. You may want to have following true to send the text message:

1: Send SMS Activity

2: The mobile phone number should be stored in the Source DE, an attribute with type phone.

3: The mobile number should have the country code.